# How would you convert a std::string to BSTR*?

Tags: c++, winapi, bstr

How would you convert a `std::string` to `BSTR*`?

```
STDMETHODIMP CMyRESTApp::rest(BSTR data, BSTR* restr)
{
    RESTClient restclient;
    RESTClient::response resp = restclient.get(data);

    Log("Response Status code: %s", resp.code);
    Log("Response Body: %s", resp.body);

    *restr = // here
    return S_OK;
}
```

I need convert the `resp.body` and this then to be returned for the `*restr` here.

Comment: Depends. What is a `BSTR*`? Tag the library you're using.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An ATL based approach is to use `ATL::CComBSTR` and then a [`Detach()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ze9wff0.aspx) (or `CopyTo(...)`) the resultant `CComBSTR` to the `BSTR*`

Something like:

```
CComBSTR temp(stlstr.c_str());
*restr = temp.Detach();
```

Else in general for `std::basic_string` you can use the Win32 API `Sys*` family of functions, such as [`SysAllocStringByteLen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221637(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`SysAllocString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221458(v=vs.85).aspx);

```
// For the `const char*` data type (`LPCSTR`);
*restr = SysAllocStringByteLen(stlstr.c_str(), stlstr.size());
```

```
// More suitable for OLECHAR
*restr = SysAllocString(stlwstr.c_str());
```

`OLECHAR` depends on the target platform, but generally it is `wchar_t`.

**Given your code**, the shortest snippet could just be;

```
*restr = SysAllocStringByteLen(resp.body.c_str(), resp.body.size());
```

*Note* these Windows API functions use the "usual" windows code page conversions, please see further MSDN documentation on how to control this if required.

Comment: Regarding the "depends on underlying char type" comment: the question specifically asks about converting from a `std::string`, not from a `std::wstring` or from an arbitrary `std::basic_string<T>`.

Comment: @jamesdlin. Correct, this was a general comment. I'll clear that up in the answer.

Comment: I have some concern about this code: `CComBSTR temp(stlstr.c_str());`. While I know there is a `CComBSTR` constructor taking a `const char*`, so this code would certainly compile, I'm not sure what kind of "code page" conversion this constructor implements. For example, I don't believe it converts from UTF-8 (possible content of the `std::string`) to UTF-16 (for the `BSTR`). Those kind of unclear ambiguous conversions can cause subtle bugs with international text. I'd suggest using code that does *explicit conversions* from whatever format the `std::string` uses to UTF-16 for the `BSTR`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` is made by `char`s; `BSTR` is usually a Unicode UTF-16 `wchar_t`-based string, with a length prefix.

Even if one could use a `BSTR` as a simple way to marshal a byte array (since the `BSTR` is length-prefixed, so it can store embedded NULs), and so potentially a `BSTR` could be used also to store non-UTF-16 text, the usual **"natural" behavior for a `BSTR` is to contain a Unicode UTF-16 `wchar_t`-string**.

So, the first problem is to clarify **what kind of encoding the `std::string` uses** (for example: Unicode UTF-8? Or some other code page?). Then you have to convert that string to Unicode UTF-16, and create a `BSTR` containing that UTF-16 string.

To convert from UTF-8 (or some other code page) to UTF-16, you can use the [**`MultiByteToWideChar()`** function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx). If the source `std::string` contains a UTF-8 string, you can use the `CP_UTF8` code page value with the aforementioned API.

Once you have the UTF-16 converted string, you can create a `BSTR` using it, and pass that as the output `BSTR*` parameter.

The main Win32 API to create a `BSTR` is [`SysAllocString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221458(v=vs.85).aspx). There are also some variants in which you can specify the string length.

Or, as a more convenient alternative, you can use the ATL's [**`CComBSTR`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f.aspx) class to wrap a `BSTR` in safe RAII boundaries, and use its [`Detach()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ze9wff0.aspx) to pass the `BSTR` as an output `BSTR*` parameter.

```
CComBSTR bstrResult( /* UTF-16 string from std::string */ );
*restr = bstrResult.Detach();
```

---

Bonus reading:

> [**Eric's Complete Guide To BSTR Semantics**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/12/52976.aspx)

Comment: Another alternative is the [_bstr_t Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx), available as a [Compiler COM Support Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yb2sfxk.aspx) in Visual Studio, if you do not want a dependency on ATL.

Answer (score 2):

This is very much  possible :

```
std::string singer("happy new year 2016");
_bstr_t sa_1(singer.c_str()); //std::string to _bstr_t
_bstr_t sa_2("Goodbye 2015"); 
std::string kapa(sa_2); //_bstr_t to std::string
```

Comment: And how you convert _bstr_t to BSTR? question is asking std::string to BSTR

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t sztBuffer = (resp.body.length() + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t);
wchar_t* pBuffer = new wchar_t[resp.body.length() + 1];
ZeroMemory(&pBuffer[0], sztBuffer);
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, resp.body.c_str(), resp.body.length(), pBuffer, sString.length());    
SysAllocString((OLECHAR*)pBuffer);
delete[] pBuffer;
```

Do not forget to deallocate it afterward.

Comment: That last paragraph is very unhelpful, it is not the contract.

Comment: I do not see how this can work if `resp.body` is a `std::string` (rather than a `std::wstring`), which is what the question is asking about.

Comment: You are right of course. To use this approach with std::string it must be converted to Unicode first.

Comment: The code is using a `std::string`. No need to not use a `std::vector<wchar_t>`, instead of the clunky array. Plus, your math for calculating the required buffer size is wrong. Let `MultiByteToWideChar` do the math for you.